# How to get IConfiguration from within Main?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The following is just for illustration purpose.

I have a `secrets.json` with the following contents:

```
{   
  "Message": "I still know what you did last summer."
}
```

And I need to seed the database with the following seeder.

```
public static class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider isp, IConfiguration c)
    {
        using (var context = isp.GetRequiredService<MyContext>())
        {
            if (context.Members.Any())
                return;

            context.Members.AddRange
            (
                new Member
                {
                    Message= c["Message"]
                }
            );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The seeder is invoked inside `Main` as follows.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebHost iwh = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (IServiceScope iss = iwh.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        IServiceProvider isp = iss.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            // IConfiguration c = ?????? 
            SeedData.Initialize(isp, c);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILogger<Program> logger = isp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
        }
    }
    iwh.Run();
}
```

## Question

How to obtain `IConfiguration c` from `Main`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do just as you do for your `MyContext` service:

```
var configuration = isp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

It'd be better if you passed both dependencies to `SeedData.Initialize` instead of a dependency and the IoC container:

```
public static void Initialize(MyContext context, IConfiguration config)
{
    ...
}

IServiceProvider isp = iss.ServiceProvider;
try
{ 
    var configuration = isp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var context = isp.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
    SeedData.Initialize(context, configuration);
}
```

With this, you at least avoid the Service Locator anti-pattern in the `Initialize` method.