# Blazor: How to get IConfiguration in Program.cs?

Tags: blazor-server-side

**IMPORTANT:** This is NOT a duplicate of [How to get IConfiguration from within Main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233629/how-to-get-iconfiguration-from-within-main) !
I have read that topic, I have read answers and comments and NO, my case is completely different.

The exact point when I need my configuration is before invoking `UseUrls` from `IHostBuilder`.
This is invoked from `Main`. My URLs are defined in `appsettings.json` file, and now I get the configuration like this:

```cs
var configuration = (
  new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true))
    .Build();
```

But this seems wrong. I mean the framework somehow loads the configuration and injects it to the services. However, the point I need it is before the services are even configured.

I also have a special execution mode for my `Main` - when `import` command argument is used, my data context is initialized (again, using configuration from `appsettings.json`) to import data from external database. When this happens, no web server is started at all, the program behaves like a console application. So again, dependency injection is not available, I instantiate the configuration as described. This is well, OK, because the initialization is done only once.

However, my "hack" initializes the `IConfiguration` and then the framework does it again. This looks like a code smell and I wonder how to fix this.

Here's my `CreateHostBuilder` method:

```cs
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
    var defaultBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    var configuration = (new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)).Build();
    return defaultBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls(configuration.GetValue<string>("InternalSiteUrl"));
    });
}
```

There **is** a better way, isn't it?